# Creating indexedDB objectStore while app is running

Tags: indexeddb

On every steps in my web app I will receive actions from server in which I need to create a brand new IDB object store. To simplify the problem assume I pretty much want to do something like this:

```
setTimeout(() => {

  // Open (or create) the database
  var open = indexedDB.open('test', open.oldVersion + 1)

  // Create the schema
  open.onupgradeneeded = () => {
    var db = open.result
    var store = db.createObjectStore('newObjectStore', { keyPath: 'id' })
  }

}, 3000)
```